# Google Apps Script apps stopped displaying images and returns 403 Forbidden

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps-script-api

As of today, my google apps script stopped displaying images.
I have been able to track it down and I'm getting the following error on my console:

[Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mo2Z2.png)

The link to the file is valid, so I'm not sure if something else has changed.
https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1RbrHllGyqgPstq6u4vnzN-RqvlFh9Xm9

I have been trying to resolve this all day and I'm just at a loss. I read that it might be due to too many users and other things that I can't figure out.

It's a very basic web app that simply displays an image based on a status.
This was working a few days ago.

I don't know what else to try.

Any insight is greatly appreciated.

I have tried recreating the app and many other things around authentication, but I haven't had any luck.
The app still works it just doesn't display the images anymore.

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your situation, I proposed an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your question and that was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: Yes, this was exactly what I needed and everything is now working. I’m curious why you say to be careful when making a file public. Is there a better way of displaying images in an apps script? Would putting the image into a Google sheet be better? I just need to be able to display one of nine possible images based on a parameter.

Comment: About `Yes, this was exactly what I needed and everything is now working.`, welcome. Thank you for letting me know. I'm glad your issue was resolved. If your question was solved, please push an accept button. Other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question that can be solved. And I think that your issue and solution will be useful for them. If you don't find the button, feel free to tell me. https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: About your new question of `Is there a better way of displaying images in an apps script? Would putting the image into a Google sheet be better?`, this thread might be useful. https://stackoverflow.com/a/60290489

Answer (score 1):

I thought that the reason for your current issue might be due to [this](https://workspaceupdates.googleblog.com/2023/10/upcoming-changes-to-third-party-cookies-in-google-drive.html). So, in the current stage, how about using the following endpoint?

**In this case, the file is required to be publicly shared. Please be careful about this.**

```
https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?sz=w1000&id={fileId}
```

- This endpoint is from https://stackoverflow.com/a/31504086
- In this endpoint, `sz=w1000` is 1000 pixels in the width.
- `{fileId}` is the file ID.

#### Note:

- When I tested this endpoint, it seemed that the endpoint worked. But, the endpoints `https://drive.google.com/uc?id={fileId}` and `https://drive.google.com/uc?id={fileId}&export=download` cannot be used. The same issue as 403 occurred.
- In the case of the above endpoint, the thumbnail image data is retrieved from the image file. But, if you want to retrieve the raw data from the file, as a simple method, I think that an API key can be also used. When the API key is used, the endpoint is as follows. This is from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63589837/7108653). When you use the following endpoints, the file is required to be publicly shared. Please be careful about this.

  - iles except for Google Docs files:

    ```
    https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/[FILEID]?alt=media&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]
    ```
  - Google Docs files:

    ```
    https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/[FILEID]/export?mimeType=[mimeType]&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]
    ```

#### References:

- [Upcoming changes to third-party cookie requirements in Google Drive](https://workspaceupdates.googleblog.com/2023/10/upcoming-changes-to-third-party-cookies-in-google-drive.html)
- [Authenticate by using API keys](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/api-keys?hl=en)
- [Download files](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads)