# Video from Google Drive folder doesn't display properly in JavaScript + HTML code

Tags: javascript, html, video, google-drive-api

I have the following situation:

I have a public shared link in a google drive folder (also public) for an mp4 video that I'd like to display in a web page.

Here's the JS code:

```
var creativelink = "https://drive.google.com/file/d/MY_FILE_ID/view?usp=sharing";

console.log("creativelink : "+creativelink);

// Regular expression to extract the file ID
var imagelink = creativelink.match(/\/file\/d\/([^/]+)/)[1];
console.log("imagelink : " + imagelink);

  creativeImage = '<video controls width="340" height="auto"><source src="https://drive.google.com/uc&id=' + imagelink + '" type="video/mp4"></video>';

console.log("creativeImage : " + creativeImage);
document.getElementById('creative').innerHTML = creativeImage;
```

And here's the HTML code:

`<div id="creative" class="text-center"></div>`

This same code used to work fine before. For some reason it's not working anymore.

The video is not displayed as expected, as you can see in the following screenshot:

[image]

There is no video, only this static image that cannot be played.

I also tried changing the code as you can see below:

```
creativeImage = '<video controls width="340" height="auto"><source src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=' + imagelink + '" type="video/mp4"></video>';
```

The result expected was the video to be played, however I have the same result as before.

I couldn't find a reasonable explanation neither a solution for this issue.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Seems like you haven't got the right embed link

Comment: What console errors are you getting?

Comment: I guessed that this thread might be the same as the reason for your situation. https://stackoverflow.com/q/77829172 In that thread, the thumbnail image is retrieved from the publicly shared image file. But, in your situation, it seems that it is required to download the raw data from the publicly shared video file. In this case, as a simple method, how about using an API key? I thought that this thread might be useful for downloading the file content with an API key. https://stackoverflow.com/a/63589837 If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Comment: @quietWind01 there is no error. The video is just not displaying.

Comment: Typically if the browser can't find a particular resource (like an image or video) it'll display an error so that's why I asked.

Comment: @JOAORF _"There is no error. The video is just not displaying"_ You might need to share a testable link. Can you put a test video and then share its link on the comments? That will get you towards a working solution much faster. (PS comment can be deleted later on if your links are supposed to be private).

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE on the matter.

Apparently this is an issue due to a google update, as you can see [here](https://support.google.com/sites/thread/253003338?hl=en&sjid=18097646299992253516-NA).

and you can track the issue [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/319531488?pli=1#comment9).

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

Waiting for the problem to be fixed.
Of course, at this point, this should be accepted as a problem by Google.

##### Functional Solution

As noted by @Tanaike, Google Drive API can be used.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/[FILEID]?key=[YOUR_API_KEY]&alt=media
```

> `[YOUR_API_KEY]`: *Get your Google Drive API Key*
>
> ---
>
> You can create a google drive API by following the official guide here:
> https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/enable-sdk

### Example

```html
<video controls crossorigin="anonymous" width="340" height="auto" src="https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/1Wd0kTWzroThS2tFaWalpdN8d_rhpgqFX?key=AIzaSyDaGmWKa4JsXZ-HjGw7ISLn_3namBGewQe&alt=media"></video>
```

##### Negative feedback according to user experiences:

When *many requests* are made, an error like the one below is encountered.

> We're sorry, but your computer or network may be sending automated queries.

### Reference

- https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/files/get